# How do I use -moz-element() to Create a Reflection?

Tags: css, css-reflections

I have a plugin that uses the following code:

```
.ms-caro3d-template .ms-slide{
   -webkit-box-reflect: below 1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(90%, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.5)));
}
```

So I looked at [CSS Reflections on Can I Use.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-reflections) to learn that it is currently a `-webkit-` only property, at least at this point.

However, Can I Use said, `Similar effect can be achieved in Firefox 4+ using the -moz-element() background property`

How would I achieve a similar effect using `-moz-element()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching two quite abandoned properties ...

About the element background, in my opinion a great pity that it didn't catch ..

```css
.test {
    width: 760px;
    height: 560px;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/750); 
    position: relative;
}


.test {
   -webkit-box-reflect: below 1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(40%, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.7)));
}

.mirror {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, white 50%, transparent ), -moz-element(#cat);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="cat"><div class="mirror"></div></div>
```

The pseudo element in FF is given the same background of the cat, rotated, and a transparency effect (fake) it's applied.

Comment: I wish CSS Reflections would gain more popularity with FF and MS. They look nice. Anyway to do with with a static image and not a background-image? (I know images do not support Pseudo Elements.)

Comment: Yes, of course, just set another element with the style that I gave to the pseudo element. The good thing about background-image: element is that it works with absolute independency of relationships between elements (it just locates the id)